# How to use react-native link in multi-app repo

Tags: react-native, code-push

I've got a multi-react-native-app repo (structured along the lines of `src/main/javascript/com/[company]/mobile/apps/...`).

Most commands in the `react-native` tool support passing a path to the entry point of the app. However, `react-native link` does not. Is there some way I'm missing that allows multi-app repos to use `react-native link` or will it attempt to link the dependencies to all apps?

I've also run into issues when trying to use `link` with some projects as they expect the `root/ios`, `root/android` structure in their `postLink.js` scripts. Is there some standard pattern they, or I, can follow that would mean they respect the project path by default?

Note `Code-Push` by Microsoft is a good example of the `root/android` expectation (at https://github.com/Microsoft/react-native-code-push/blob/master/scripts/postlink/android/postlink.js at the time of posting).

Thanks